# Determine the radius of convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n^{1/3}}z^n$ (by the ratio test if possible)

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, power-series

Determine the radius of convergence of the following power series:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{n^{1/3}}z^n$

---

Applying the ratio test gives $\frac{({n+1})^{({n+1})^{1/3}}}{n^{n^{1/3}}}z<1$. So $z<\frac{n^{n^{1/3}}}{({n+1})^{({n+1})^{1/3}}}<\frac{n^{({n+1})^{1/3}}}{({n+1})^{({n+1})^{1/3}}} \leq 1$. Since this last expression tends to $1$ as $n$ tends to infinity.

I think I would need to approximate $z$ below with an expression which also tends to $1$ to show that the radius of convergence is $1$. But any other idea is welcomed.

Comment: Just use the root test.

Comment: Yes, thank you, I assume it can be solved by the root test but WolframAlpha says 'by the ratio test' so I am curious.

Answer (score 3):

The radius $r$ of convergence is such that

$$\frac{1}{r} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \sqrt[n]{n^{n^{1/3}}}= \lim_{n\to \infty} n^{n^{-2/3}} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \exp(n^{-2/3}\log n) =  \exp(0) = 1,$$

thus $r = 1$.